# Fitltering in findall

Tags: prolog, prolog-findall

I have rule:

```
best_fit(Team, Enemies, Result, List) :-
    findall((H, E), score(H, Enemies, Team, E), List),
```

where score definition is:

```
score(Hero, Enemies, Team, Result) :- 
   hero(Hero),
...
```

I would like to find only that (H,E) where H is not in Enemies or Team. I tried to later `exclude` but the results are tuples and it is kind of complicated to make it work. Is there a way to filter it out in `findall` method? How can I approach this?

Answer (score 2):

You can enforce that in the goal:

```
best_fit(Team, Enemies, Result, List) :-
    findall((H, E), (
        score(H, Enemies, Team, E),
        \+ member(H, Enemies),
        \+ member(H, Team),
    ), List).
```

So here we modified the goal such that it is satisfied if `score(H, Enemies, Team, E)` *and* `H` is *not* a member of `Enemies`, and `H` is not a member of `Team`.

Comment: Many thanks, much cleaner than excluding etc. I kind of tried to do it like this but sth was not right, anyway it works now !